# Mobile upload file to S3 using a Rails Rest API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, mobile, amazon-s3, refile

I have a web app in Rails that has a profile image upload, I`m using Refile gem to upload the photo direct to Amazon S3.

But now I need to do this upload from a mobile app too.
Witch is the best way to do that?

I think about a Rest API in Rails that receives the binary data and then uses Async Jobs (Sidekiq) to upload to Amazon S3, but and not sure if the approach is best way.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: App in iOS and Android backend using rails

Comment: On iOS you might want to look at using AFNetworking for uploading your image to a rails RESTful API.